# Android PrintManager get callback

Tags: android, printing

I am using the PrintManager to print a webpage, how can my activity get a callback once printing was successfull?
I am using this code:

```
    // Get a PrintManager instance
    PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

    // Get a print adapter instance
    PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();

    // Create a print job with name and adapter instance
    String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
    PrintJob printJob = printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
            new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
    // Save the job object for later status checking
    //mPrintJobs.add(printJob);
```

Comment: I haven't used it but it looks like this would be done in your `PrintAdapter` with [onFinish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/PrintDocumentAdapter.html#onFinish())

Comment: Yes, I saw that methode in the docs, but how would I implement it/overwrite it?

Comment: Create a class which `extends PrintDocumentAdapter`. Then `@Override` the necessary methods. Basically as you would with an Activity, ArrayAdapter class, and others.

Comment: I just skimmed and don't know anything about the site but http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Custom_Document_Printing_Tutorial

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a wrapper around the `PrintDocumentAdapter` received from the webView. Then you can put a hook in the onFinish().

```
public class PrintDocumentAdapterWrapper extends PrintDocumentAdapter{

     private final PrintDocumentAdapter delegate;
     public PrintDocumentAdapterWrapper(PrintDocumentAdapter adapter){
         super();
         this.delegate = adapter;
     }

     public void onFinish(){
          delegate.onFinish();
          //insert hook here
     }

     //override all other methods with a trivial implementation calling to the delegate
}
```

And here is how to use it in your code :

```
// Get a PrintManager instance
PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager)    this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

// Get a print adapter instance and wrap it in my own adapter
PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = new PrintDocumentAdapterWrapper(webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter());

// Create a print job with name and adapter instance
String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
PrintJob printJob = printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
        new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
// Save the job object for later status checking
//mPrintJobs.add(printJob);
```

Comment: how can we distinguish between saved->finished and canceled in onFinish method?

Comment: When you press print button ```onFinish()``` is calling, how can I determine whether it is a success or not ?